# Consulta en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

tengo una tabla con usuarios que tienen los siguientes Datos, DNI,ID,LEGAJO.

lo que yo quiero hacer es bsucar un usuario por DNI pero el DNI puede coincidir solamente en alguna parte, no completo. por ejemplo, tengo un DNI 37762956, y yo la búsqueda la realizo con el DNI "037762956" y no lo encuentra al tener un 0 adelante. ya intente utilizando el operador LIKE y nada. tanto por izquierda o derecha, o en los dos lados. 
Yo intentaba algo así:

```
select samaccountName from AD
where Employeeid LIKE @UsuariosABuscar+'%' o colocando el '%' de izquierda, blabla.
```

Aguardo sugerencias.
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Existen distintas formas de obtener el resultado mediante la eliminación de ceros que se encuentren al inicio. Aquí un par de ejemplos.

```
CREATE TABLE #Prueba(
    DNI varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO #Prueba VALUES('37762956');

DECLARE @UsuariosABuscar varchar(10) = '037762956'

SELECT *
FROM #Prueba
WHERE DNI = CAST( TRY_CAST( @UsuariosABuscar AS int) AS varchar(10));

SELECT *
FROM #Prueba
WHERE DNI = STUFF( @UsuariosABuscar, 1, NULLIF( PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @UsuariosABuscar), 0)-1, '');


DROP TABLE #Prueba;
```

Comment: Luis buen día, te consulto por que el try_cast no me tomaría , en el segundo ejemplo el stuff y el nullif como funcionarían? se agradece la ayuda.

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con que el try_cast no te tomaría. Está ahí para evitar errores por valores que no puedan ser convertidos a int. 

El NULLIF está para convertir en NULL los valores que no tengan algún caracter distinto a cero. STUFF reemplaza sólo los ceros iniciales con una cadena vacía.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma en la que se puede solucionar el inconveniente:

```
CREATE TABLE ##usuario(
usuario varchar(10),
documento varchar(11)
)

INSERT INTO ##usuario values('JCABRERA','37762956')
INSERT INTO ##usuario values('JGONZALEZ','76207756')
INSERT INTO ##usuario values('PAYALA','98726792')
INSERT INTO ##usuario values('PAYALA','98720792')

DECLARE @DOC VARCHAR(11);
SET @DOC = '037762956';
SELECT *
FROM ##USUARIO AS USUA
WHERE REPLACE(USUA.DOCUMENTO, '0', '') LIKE '%' + REPLACE(@DOC, '0', '')+ '%';
```